# how do i popluate the roles table in a database through the JSP

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I have got two tables ( User and Roles) with many-to-many relation. I have a requirement to populate the Roles table through the form which collects the User details(for User table) along with the Roles user selects. How do I pass on the details of the Roles to its corresponding table. An example would help

Comment: Use spring security..

Comment: an example would really be helpful @Sumesh TG

Comment: Create roles table with `ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER,ROLE_MANAGER....etc `with unique id's, Use foriegn key to connect roles with users table.

Comment: isn't it the job of Hibernate to create tables as it encounters entities and the operations upon them @Sumesh TG

Comment: Yes. If you need ORM in your project use HIbernate or JPA.